# How to retrieve the list of models for model A which contains a foreign key to B?

Tags: python, django

```
class Member( models.Model ):
    id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    ...

class Address( models.Model ):
    member = models.ForeignKey( Member )
```

I have the pk for a Member & can retrieve a Member; but I want to retrieve the possibly more than one Address(es) that point to that Member. How do I achieve that in django ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Address.objects.filter(member=somemember)
```

or

```
Address.objects.filter(member_id=somemember_pk)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Address( models.Model ):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name="addresses")
```

Then use `member.addresses`.

Comment: The problem is: Given a Member, retrieve Addresses.

Comment: The solution is: `member.addresses`